# Deform svg object

Tags: css, svg, css-grid

I have an svg object as follows:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="../static/somatocart.svg" >
```

I have it placed inside a grid-type dive with the following placing style:

```
object{
    grid-area: 3 / 4 / 20 / 15;
    object-fit: fill;
}
```

I know normally we want images to preserve ratio, but I want the svg to be deformed as needed to fill those grid spaces. As it is supposed to be responsible, sometimes will be wider, sometimes larger. But the object keeps its original ratio, only following the width according to grid.

Thank you in advance for your help!

```css
div#somatochart {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(19, 5.26%);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(25, 4%);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
}

div#somatochart object {
  grid-area: 3 / 4 / 20 / 15;
  object-fit: fill;
}
```

```html
<div id='somatochart'>
  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://tanukilibros.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/somatocart.svg">
                </object>
</div>
```

Comment: Unlikely the SVG will deform unless it has the correct [PreserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio)

Comment: I.e. what's in somatocart.svg